# Why Java Web Start doesn't update jnlp settings, even if "update" is specified and version is changed?

Tags: java, caching, jnlp

I did the following steps:

- Cleared java cache.
- Launched the applet (via `javaws <url of jnlp file>`)
- Observed the fresh entry in java cache. Let's say that this jnlp file had version `6.43` and `-Xss4m` in `java-vm-args`.
- Then, I changed version to `6.44`, `java-vm-args` to `-Xss5m`, and ran `javaws` again.
- Via `wireshark`, I observed that jnlp file was indeed downloaded. But when the app started, `-Xss` setting still displayed 4mb. Any number of retries don't fix the problem - only full clear of the cache can force JavaWS to accept new version.

I'm using JDK 1.7.0_45, on XUbuntu 12.04, 64bit.

Here is the full jnlp file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="7.0+" codebase="http://192.168.0.47/parrot/" href="http://192.168.0.47/parrot//jnlp.php" version="6.44">
  <information>
    <title>Parrot</title>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"
          java-vm-args="-Xss5m" />
    <jar href="http://192.168.0.47/parrot//Parrot.jar" main="true" />
    <jar href="http://192.168.0.47/parrot//Splash.jar" download="progress" />
    <property name="jnlp.packEnabled" value="true" />
  </resources>
  <application-desc name="Parrot"
                    main-class="launch.Jnlp"
                    progress-class="parrot.splash.Splash" />
  <update check="always" policy="always" />
</jnlp>
```

As you can see, `update` was set to `always`.

While I (as a developer) have no problem with clearing caches, users of my app are definitely not always that smart, and thus they are doomed to start the app with wrong jvm args. Is there some way to fix this?